# Keep MUI Autocomplete open after selecting an option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have certain options on  my Autocomplete component that if selected I would like to keep the component opened.

Unfortunately whenever clicking  the `onChange`, it automatically closes the Autocomplete and I can't seem to find an option to keep it opened. Is there a way around this?

For this example, I've added a flag on the option I wish to use when keeping the Autocomplete opened. It looks like this:

```
const top100Films = [
  { label: "DONT CLOSE ME IF IM SELECTED", year: 2023, dontClose: true },
  { label: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { label: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  ...
]
```

Then, in  the Autocomplete I'd like to somehow prevent it from closing on  the onChange:

```
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      {...otherProps}
      onChange={(_, value) => {
        if (value?.dontClose) {
          console.log("please dont close");
          // Anything I can do for it not to close?
        } else {
          console.log("close me");
        }
      }}
    />
  );
```

Out of desperation, I've attempted to add a state which would force it to stay opened if I were to click on the dontClose option, but that hasn't worked either. Its basically:

```
export default function ComboBox() {
  const [dontClose, setDontClose] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      {...otherProps}
      open={dontClose ? true : undefined} // attempt at keeping it opened
      onChange={(_, value) => {
        if (value?.dontClose) {
          console.log("please dont close");
          setDontClose(true);
        } else {
          console.log("close me");
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

I'm currently out of ideas. Anything else I can do to keep it Autocomplete opened for this case?

Here is  full demo of what I have so far: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-sound-fcszfk?file=/src/Demo.tsx

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a prop that you can pass in to the `Autocomplete` component called `disableCloseOnSelect`. This should allow the functionality that you want.

You'll just need to mess around with updating the state correctly so the state updates don't lag behind. Like, if your default for `disableCloseOnSelect` is `false` then selecting an option that won't close will cause the next render to stay open.